# issue with date format, some dates doesnt format properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue:

I have a column with date in `dd.mm.yyyy` format, I replace `.` with `-` and use 
loop with:

```
Cells(i, 2).Value = Format(Cells(i, 2).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Because I need to make it `yyyy-mm-dd`.

It works mostly fine, but formats of a few dates not properly like it makes *5th April* into *4th May*.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your current cell values are stored as strings that happen to only *look* like dates.

Your regional settings will be defaulting to date format `mm-dd-yyyy`.  So where dates are ambiguous (as 5th April is) Excel will default to that interpretation.

You should really store the dates as real dates, and use formatting to display them as you wish.  Somethig like

```
If Cells(i, 2).Value Like "##-##-####" Then
    s = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Cells(i, 2).Value = DateSerial(Mid$(s, 7, 4), Mid$(s, 4, 2), Left(s, 2))
    Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
End If
```

If you insist on storing them as strings, use

```
If Cells(i, 2).Value Like "##-##-####" Then
    s = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = Format$(DateSerial(Mid$(s, 7, 4), Mid$(s, 4, 2), Left(s, 2)), "yyyy-mm-dd")
End If
```